# How to generate an OAuth token with two header parameters using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, salesforce, restsharp

I'm trying to set request content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in RestSharp. I.m working with SalesForce REST API. I'm trying to put a request and pass the parameters. I spent multpile hours trying do this without RestSharp but after a lot of research I came to a conclusion that RestSharp is the best way to do it. I'm getting an error saying:

> StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: -1)

This is my code.

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;



namespace Restsharper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var client = new RestClient("https://##--dev.##.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.POST };
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("clientid", "clientsecret");
       // request.
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
        request.AddParameter("password", "password123#");
        request.AddParameter("username", "username123");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the Content body that comes back in the response it should give you a more detailed explanation of what's missing. I'm not familiar with Salesforce but I had a quick look at their website and it seems that you shouldn't use the client.Authenticator, rather add "clientid" and "clientsecret" as parameters. See here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

Comment: @JanusPienaar I have used the values of clientid and clientsecret int client.Authenticator, which accepts the values directly.

Comment: @JanusPienaar I have changed client.Authenticator and added them as parameters. I have looked at the content and it says invalid grant now. I checked the request using fiddler and seen that the username = user@user.com and password = password# are not being sent properly. I tried to encode them using uri.escapedatasting and webutility.urlencode but still no luck. Any idea on how to encode username and password